# Importing Grails project to IntelliJ IDEA using Gradle fails

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, grails, grails3

When importing a Grails 3+ project to IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate, the Gradle build stops at “Starting Gradle Daemon...”.

[Screenshot of IntelliJ build window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u5nCM.png)

This happens when a new Grails 3 project is created using the command “grails create-app projectName” and imported to IntelliJ IDEA using Gradle.

My system configuration:

- macOS Catalina
- IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate 2020.1
- Java 8
- Grails 3.3.5
- Groovy 2.4.15

The Gradle build fails with no other error messages.

“gradle”, “./gradlew”, “./gradlew bootRun” commands work as expected on the terminal.

Comment: What JDK distribution are you using? I've seen intellij fail with zulu just as you describe. Try using a different jdk8 (eg java.net jdk or oracle) and make sure you're on the latest version.

Comment: @erichelgeson zulu distribution was the issue! Using BellSoft 8.0.252-librca JDK distribution fixed the issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Check the **Gradle JVM** which is set for project and make sure it is compatible for the Gradle version used in project:

[image]

Try setting different JDKs including the 1.8 JDK there.

Comment: For me `JAVA_HOME` option had been selected in freshly created Grails 4 plugin. I was need to manually change it to the other JDK(1.8) to make Gradle work. Maybe it's something to do with `sdkman`. Cause my `JAVA_HOME` env var points to the `~/.sdkman/candidates/java/current`.